Can you make an embedded Vimeo player open the transcript panel by default..And if possible, toggle the timing setting in transcripts settings to off?
I am embedding the Vimeo player into my site and wish to have the player open with the transcript panel open by default. The embed code is here:
<div style='padding:56.23% 0 0 0;position:relative;'><iframe src='https://player.vimeo.com/video/949240xxx?badge=0&amp;autopause=0&amp;player_id=0&amp;app_id=58479&amp;texttrack=en-x-autogen' frameborder='0' allow='autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture; clipboard-write' style='position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;' title='SignCallVideo'></iframe></div><script src='https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js'></script> 

Is there a way to do this using their API?
I was able to make the video play the generated english subtitles by default by adding &texttrack=en-x-autogen to the end of my src URL. This is ok, but I really would like to have the transcript panel open by default.
